# Exhaustive Grid Search for feature selection

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, feature-selection, hyperparameters

I've been working with several ranking feature selection approaches. As you may know, these type of algorithms rank the features according to some specific method (e.g., statistical, sparse learning, ecc.) and they're ruled by several hyper-parameters which must be tuned in order to achieve the best results.

The state of the art presents different approach for the tuning of the parameters and by looking over the web I came across the following method: *the grid-search approach*. As specified at this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html), a search consist of the the following steps:

1. Feature selector
2. Method for searching or sampling candidates;
3. Parameter space
4. Cross-validation scheme
5. Score function.

I summarized the following steps (starting from point 3) in this piece of code:

```
tuned_parameters = {

'LASSO':    {'alpha': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]},

}

# pick the i-th feature selector
for fs_name, fs_model in slb_fs.iteritems():

    comb = []
    params_name = []
    for name, tun_par in tuned_parameters[fs_name].iteritems():
        comb.append(tun_par)
        params_name.append(name)

    # function for creating all the exhausted combination of the parameters
    print ('\t3 - Creating parameters space: ')
    combs = create_grid(comb)

    for comb in combs:

        # pick the i-th combination of the parameters for the k-th feature selector
        fs_model.setParams(comb,params_name,params[fs_name])

        # number of folds for k-CV
        k_fold = 5

        X = dataset.data
        y = dataset.target
        kf = KFold(n_splits=k_fold)

        print ('\t4 - Performing K-cross validation: ')
        for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
            X_train, X_test = X[train_index, :], X[test_index, :]
            y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

            print ('\t5.1 - Performing feature selection using: ', fs_name)
            idx = fs_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

            # At this point I have the ranked features

            print ('5.2 - Classification...')
            for n_rep in xrange(step, max_num_feat + step, step): 

                # Using classifier to evaluate the algorithm performance on the test set using incrementally the retrieved feature  (1,2,3,...,max_num_feat)

                X_train_fs = X_train[:, idx[0:n_rep]]
                X_test_fs = X_test[:, idx[0:n_rep]]

                _clf = clf.Classifier(names=clf_name, classifiers=model)
                DTS = _clf.train_and_classify(X_train_fs, y_train, X_test_fs, y_test)

        # Averaging results of the CV
        print('\t4.Averaging results...')
```

At the point 5.1, I use a classifier for evaluate the performance obtained by the selected feature selector on a subset of feature (in my case I incrementally use them since the feature are ranked) and average the results by means of a Cross-validation scheme. The results I have at this point is an average accuracy score for each subset of features (e.g., 1: 70%, 2:75, 3:77%,...,N:100%).

Obviously, the latter averaged results are obtained for each combination of the parameters (see the table below). 
For instance, supposing the current feature selector need just to tune the parameter *alpha*, the results i'd get are listed in the following table.

[image]

My question is: Is there any known approach for picking the best configuration of parameters based on the achieved results for all the features or a fixed number of them?

I thought about averaging the results and use it as the "best configuration" but i don't think it can work. Does any of you know any specific approach?

I would be very thankful if someonecould help me.

Comment: ??? I think the intention is to pick the best result and use that feature selector together with that parameter set. Feature selection can be seen just as another parameter.

Comment: @kutschkem My problem is how to pick the best result based on the accuracy score i got once i run the feature selector with different value of the hyper-parameter (e.g., alpha) and by varying the number of feature (1 to num_max_feats). I do not understand your point...

Comment: You have a 2D optimization problem (feature number, alpha) and apparently a table which tells you the accuracy for every combination. What is wrong with picking the combination (feature number, alpha) where the accuracy is maximal? I assume what you mean is that you want an alpha that works best independent of the number of features. If that is the case, I think it is not clear there exists such an alpha, I don't think they are independent.

Comment: @kutschkem Yes, it can be seen as a 2D optimization problem. Can you please be more specif when you say to pick the combination where the accuracy is maximal. Do i take the maximal averaged accuracy? If not, which measure do you recommend me to use? I agree with the fact alpha may give different results depending on the number of feature and that these two variables (feature number, alpha) are not independent one from each other. I've also thought to use a majority vote approach on the results table and pick that alpha that achieve more votes. Do you think it's a reasonable approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At least one part of the question resolves around which measure you want to use to choose your hyperparameters. This depends on your problem, but in general you should not use averaged accuracy as your measure.

### Why is averaged accuracy not the right measure?

Averaged accuracy emphasizes the largest class, or is more sensitive to it. However often that is not the most interesting class.

A better measure is often the [F1-measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), which is similar to averaged accuracy, but not the same. It is the harmonic average of precision and recall, and commonly used in Information Retrieval tasks, where the "positive" class is commonly small and the "negative" class very large.

F1-Measure seems to be critized outside of information retrieval tasks for being biased, similar to accuracy. A better measure seems to be [Matthews Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient). This measure uses all cells of the confusion matrix and doesn't suffer from the same biases as the other two measures. I have no experience with this measure, but according to the Wikipedia article it is recommended by Davide Chicco in his paper "[Ten quick tips for machine learning in computational biology](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13040-017-0155-3)".

Comment: Ok. I understand your concern about the type of measure to adopt but sadly this answer does't solve my problem. I actually need a methodology (regardless the type of measure) for picking a fair configuration by tuning the hyper-parameters when the number of features vary. I've advised the grid-search because it's a well know method that might be adapted to my problem. What i need is either a pre or a post procedure that can tell me the most fair/best hyper-parameters configuration for a fixed number of features (e.g., the first 10, 20, 50, 100 features).

Comment: @DavideNardone Why not save the best configuration for every feature count and, depending on which count you currently use, check which configuration you should use? Does it HAVE to be one configuration that you use regardless of the number of features?

Comment: Yes. The idea I've already implemented consists of: 

1. Voting the best configuration (highest accuracy) when the number of features varies and then
2. picking the configuration which has the largest number of votes (largest number of 1 in a row)

This approach is also know as a "majority vote approach". I've been wondering (by asking this question) if in the state of the art there was a less naive approach...

Answer (score 1):

Ciao @DavideNardone

Regarding the performance measure, @kutschkem is right: if you're working on a binary classification and your method generates a confusion matrix, use the **Matthews correlation coefficient (MCC)** instead of accuracy or F1 score or other rates. Please take a look at Tip 8 in my [paper](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13040-017-0155-3) for the scientific reasons.

Regarding how to choose the best configuration for your model, I think your majority approach is on the right direction.
I would reframe it this way:

1. Voting the best configuration (highest **Matthews correlation coefficient MCC**) when the number of features varies and then
2. Picking the configuration which has the largest number of vote.

Perhaps this approach is not the best in the world, but surely has a strong scientific background (the majority vote, in fact, is used in [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) as well).

Also, I think Stack Overflow might not be the best place where to ask computational intelligence questions; I would suggest you to move/re-ask this question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or other [Stack Exchange websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms).

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately the classification cases i've been dealing to is not a binary one. However, beside from the the accuracy measure i may use, i was looking for some advices on fine tuning parameters for feature selection. Anyhow, thanks for the advice!